# Фильтрация данных. Поиск по таблице

Tags: java, mysql, search

Здравствуйте, возникла проблема. У меня есть таблица пользователей. Я хочу создать такой текстовый іnput, в который во время ввода имени, появляются все имена, которые совпадают с введенным текстом (на данный момент).

Например в таблице есть три человека:

1. Вася Пупкин
2. Петя Иванов
3. Вася Петров

Когда вводишь в input Вася, сразу выпадающий список предлагает выбрать человека из двух Василиев, вводишь дальше Пу... уже предлагает конкретного человека.
Таких примеров много на разных сайтах, как минимум гугл.

Но, для начинающего человека, который только осваивает веб программирование, эта задача немного сложна. И её сложность состоит не только в том, что не знаю как реализовать, а нагуглить нужной информации уже сложно. Потому что, каждый человек называет это по разному, и каждый делает это каким то невероятным способом (да и в основном везде php код). А я верю, что это не такое уж сложное действие. Спасибо!

язык Java, DB MySQL.

p.s Хотя бы киньте ссылок на темы (на английском или славянским языком, это не столь существенно), где эта проблема описывается.

Comment: это будет настольное приложение или веб? или какое-нибудь другое?

Comment: веб приложение, использую jsp и servlet (да конечно устаревшая технология, но надо начать с простого).

Answer (score 1):

Реализовать такое поле для ввода можно следующим образом:

1. Сервлет, который будет искать в базе по введенным символам пользователей и возвращать список совпадений в виде json. Для связи с базой можно использовать чистый JDBC или какой-нибудь ORM фреймворк, например JPA.
2. Страница с полем для ввода - jsp или просто html
3. Библиотека jQuery и плагин Autocomplete
4. Примерно вот такой код:

   ```
   // id вашего поля
   $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
     // URL сервлета
     source: "/user/search",
     minLength: 2
   });
   ```

Comment: Нельзя будет выполнить запрос для всех имен, записать их в сессию или в  запрос, потом как нибудь вытащить с помощью autocomplete, немного сложно все представить как это работает, оно шлет запрос на каждый символ ? Как тогда делать такой запрос ?

Comment: а если у вас будет 100000 пользователей? Autocomplete можно настроить на желаемое поведение - сколько символов ждать, сколько времени ждать между символами и пр. мой код это очень примитивный пример.

Comment: Тогда одного не пойму, как правильно делать запросы к базе ?

Comment: я дополнил ответ этой информацией

Comment: Я понимаю как с базой связаться) Я не понимаю как будет делаться запрос, как только я введу 2 символа, я должен их как то вытащить request-ом, потом сделать запрос `select name from users where name =  'Ва'; ` Потом вернуть строку со всеми именами, разделенные запятой и создать json ?

Comment: запрос сделает плагин. вам надо только принять его в сервлете и выдать ответ. конкретный формат ответа вы можете настроить в плагине. я дал json как стандартный вариант.